# Laravel has-many-through with multiple intermediate tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to develop multiple-shop eCommerce platform.
So the following tables created:

```
shops: id, name, ...
products: id, shop_id, ...
orders: id, ...
order_details: id, order_id, product_id, ...
```

And this is the summery of my models' relationships:

- **Shop->products**: Shop hasMany Product
- **Product->shop**: Product belongsTo Shop
- **Order->details**: Order hasMany OrderDetail
- **OrderDetail->order**: OrderDetail belongsTo Order
- **OrderDetail->product**: OrderDetail belongsTo Product
- **Product->orders**: Product hasMany OrderDetail

Now, **1:** Is it possible to define **Shop->orders** relationship?(It seams has-many-through not works in this case due to multiple intermediate tables)

**2:** If it is possible, could the **shop->orders->details** contains only the records related to shop products?

*It should be note that each Order may contain products from multiple shops but the **shop->orders->details** relation should contains only the shop products.*

Answer (score 3):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with support for `BelongsToMany`: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Shop extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Order::class, [Product::class, 'order_details']);
    }
}
```